# How to update Edit Control using SetDlgItemText method?

Tags: winforms, mfc, formatting

I am trying to do it with this code.

```
short int R = 128
CString str;
str.Format(_T("Test %d",R));
SetDlgItemText(EDIT,str);
```

However, the output I get at Edit Control is

```
Test 1955401504
```

Short int R is converted improperly. Do you have an idea how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closing `)` in:

```
str.Format(_T("Test %d",R));
```

is in the wrong place.

Try this:

```
str.Format(_T("Test %d"),R);
```